# Win 8.1 where OWA suddenly reports "OWA does not support the client computer"

Tags: windows-8, outlook-web-access

I was accessing an Outlook account when suddenly I got this error on the Win 8.1 machine.

> Outlook Web App doesn't support this type of client computer.

I am able to access the same account from WIN-Xp or Android so I have the id and password, and url.

One odd thing I noted is that the option to select the Light version is grayed out.
I have tried to clear the cache to reset things. Is there possibly an outside cache in addition to the IE browser?

Comment: What browser are you using?  This sounds like is IE11 incompatible with the version of exchange your using upgrade it to 2013 for guaranteed support

Answer (score 1):

You'll need to do the following:

1. Set Compatibility View on in IE 11
2. Use F10 to display IE menu
3. Choose Compatibility View settings
4. Add the OWA webmail site to the list

This allows the OWS access to work again (which may depends perhaps on the Exchange server version).